# What happened to std::cspan?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, std-span

`std::span` has been voted into C++20. I assumed that along with `std::span`, there would be a convenience alias defined like this:

```
template <class T, size_t Extent = dynamic_extent>
using cspan = span<const T, Extent>;
```

To me, this seems like a really handy alias. I'd probably use `cspan` more often than `span`! According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/span), `cspan` doesn't exist. There's one mention of `cspan` in [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1085r2.md) which seems to imply that it was in the standard at some point. I can't find any other mentions.

So what happened to `cspan`? Was it removed? Did it ever exist at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, `cspan` does not exist and has never existed. The only name change is that `span` used to be spelled `array_view`

The reference in [P1085R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1085r2.md):

> ```
> |  3  |  Make span operate only on const T, (rename cspan, obviously :D)  |
> ```

is a joke, as implied by the `:D` (note that [C-SPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-SPAN) is a cable network that broadcasts federal government proceedings). The actual proposal was that `span<T>` change to behave like today's `span<T const>` (and cheekily be renamed *to* `cspan`).

Just write `span<T const>`. It's a full 5 characters longer than `cspan<T>`, with the added benefit that more people will know what `span` is.

Comment: **five** characters longer.  " const" (six characters), versus "c" (one character) - I suspect you forgot to count the space.

Comment: @MartinBonner I wrote five characters! Shitty edit.

Comment: I think that’s rather unfortunate. 5 characters is 6.25% of a line! Of course, I could always define it myself but I truly believe that this is something that should be part of the standard library.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I mean, 5 is also 11.9% of 42, but that doesn't really make the number any larger. I've had a `span`-like type in my codebase for years and I've never even heard anybody even suggest that writing out `const` was too long. It's not even in a place where terseness adds much value.